# How to do logout using retrofit in android

Tags: android, api, retrofit, logout

I would like to do `logout` function in my android application. First, I use `retrofit` to do `login` and now, I want to logout using retrofit. I have one `button (logout)` in `FinalConfirm.java`, When I click it, I want to do logout.

```
private void LoginUser() {
    NetworkEngine.getInstance().postLogin(edt_login_email_phone.getText().toString(), edt_login_password.getText().toString(), new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void success(User user, Response response) {
            if (chk_login_remember_password.isChecked()) {
                StoreUtil.getInstance().saveTo("users", user);
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: do you use & store cookies for session management?

Comment: so how do you manage sessions?

Comment: simply call a function for logout and in `success` remove the current user from "users" ! what's the problem with that?

Comment: Please, explain with demo or reference  website  :D

Comment: Sorry but you haven't provided much information, do you use cookies to manage session or tokens or ... ? maybe take a look at this tutorial https://futurestud.io/blog/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit